# Chrome extension: accessing hidden elements

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to access spans with "display: none" parameter from within the chrome extension?

Comment: You can access any DOM elements, it doesn't matter what style they have.

Comment: Do you want to get only the spans that have the `display: none` css property or are you having trouble selecting those spans as part of a different query (meaning you tried for example selecting spans with a certain class and only visible spans were selected)? I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir the elements I am trying to access only appear when I click one specific button: the drop-down appears. I was trying to Xpath and JSselector, nothing seems to work. Same thing with "getElementByClassName", it just doesn't see the elements I need. Before searching I also use button.click() trying to open that menu